# Jcrop: How to overcome low resolution images after cropping?

Tags: image, dpi, jcrop, todataurl, image-quality

I am currently working on a solution, where I crop an image to a rectangle using jcrop so I can use it as a texture for a 3D cube (in three.js)
**AND** I can save the cropped area as an image on the server.

The Problem here is, that the cropped image looks not good, it has low quality.
At first I thought it has something to do with the DPI, because it saves in 96 DPI, but some images that I upload do also have 96 dpi and have good quality.

I think it has something to do with jcrop. Do someone know or had any experience with jcrop regarding this issue? Or should I use a different plugin?

[Original Image](http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/32/6878307-high-resolution-wallpaper.jpg)

[Cropped Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa3n4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use php resize image system.
i am using it on my website.

Check demo resize wallpaper (check screen shoot) : [Happy diwali wallpaper](http://www.wallpaperg.com/17/festival-and-occasion/6514/diwali-wallpapers/12272/happy-diwali-image.shtml)

and original wallpaper (download button as well as below resize option at the page) [diwali wallpaper](http://www.wallpaperg.com/uploads/file/1476284246-happy-diwali-image-file.jpg)

you ca use

```
function resize($newWidth, $targetFile, $originalFile) {

$info = getimagesize($originalFile);
$mime = $info['mime'];

switch ($mime) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
                $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
                $image_save_func = 'imagejpeg';
                $new_image_ext = 'jpg';
                break;

        case 'image/png':
                $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefrompng';
                $image_save_func = 'imagepng';
                $new_image_ext = 'png';
                break;

        case 'image/gif':
                $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefromgif';
                $image_save_func = 'imagegif';
                $new_image_ext = 'gif';
                break;

        default: 
                throw new Exception('Unknown image type.');
}

$img = $image_create_func($originalFile);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($originalFile);

$newHeight = ($height / $width) * $newWidth;
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
imagecopyresampled($tmp, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

if (file_exists($targetFile)) {
        unlink($targetFile);
}
$image_save_func($tmp, "$targetFile.$new_image_ext");
```

}

Source: [Resize images with PHP, support PNG, JPG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596794/resize-images-with-php-support-png-jpg)